# Android Issues: Not converting All fetched phone contacts numbers in to Json format

Tags: android

I have fetched all contacts number from Android phone But not converting all phonenumbers in to json format. In some android phone ,it is working but in my phone Samsung Duos ,it is not working. It gives output like that

URL IS NOW

```
{"data":[
 {"phone":"+9187678965433","name":"Home"},
 {"phone":"+9178961042","name":"Vikash(bang)"}, 
 {"phone":"+91826543748","name":"Chandan(mota)"},
 {"phone":"+91867868199","name":"Amit Singh"},
 {"phone":"+9143228811","name":"Jimmi Sinha"},
 {"phone":"+91989769610","name":"Nagar(Aone)"},
 {"phone":"+919465436261","name":"Shahi(Biet)"},
 {"phone":"+917576540555","name":"Pankaj(Biet)"},
"name":"P
```

Please tell me what is the problem.

This is my code

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
         Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

         JSONObject jobj ;
         JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

         if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                   // System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                    // get the phone number
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                           new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                           phone = pCur.getString(
                                 pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                           name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


                           jobj = new JSONObject();
                           try {

                            jobj.put("phone", phone);
                            jobj.put("name", name);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                           arr.put(jobj);
                          System.out.println("phone" + phone); 
                        // response = callContactList();
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
             }


                   jobj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jobj.put("data", arr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String st = jobj.toString().trim();


            response = callContactList(st);
            }
```

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: and any exceptions from logcat

Comment: No exception...just converted few contact numbers of my phone in json.....But In other phone,all contact nubmbers is converting in json format..

Comment: does it stops on the same contact every time? if yes, then it could be a special case, that contact, might have some NULL values or other reasons

Comment: Thanks,Yazan....It is solved